# pure Nodejs server chart library

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts, server-side

The most common solution to create charts on the server with Node.js is to emulate the DOM and use a js client chart library. 
e.g: http://blog.stevenedouard.com/how-to-render-chart-js-charts-serverside/ or spawning some process.

these solutions use mainly JSDOM and node canvas, that have dependencies (as Cairo) not always easy to replicate on different systems/OS (yes, Docker helps in this).

Is there any 'pure' Nodejs solution/package to dinamically generate charts, save them to a stream that don't require native dependencies?